# How to set multiple command line argument for single Flag in erl

Tags: erlang, init

In Erlang,

we can pass multiple input to the Erlang system by command line arguments.

> erl -sname name1 -setcookie abcd

how to pass multiple values for a single Flag?

Answer (score 1):

We can able to sent multiple Values to a single Flag.

Values are differentiated by **Space** character

```
erl -key1 val1 val2 val3
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.3  (abort with ^G)
1> init:get_argument(key1).
{ok,[["val1","val2","val3"]]}
```

You can pass multiple Key Values pairs like

```
erl -key1 val1 val2 val3 -key2 val11 val12 val13
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.3  (abort with ^G)
1> init:get_argument(key2).
{ok,[["val11","val12","val13"]]}
2> init:get_argument(key1).
{ok,[["val1","val2","val3"]]}
```

If you pass key more than one time you get the values as like

```
 erl -key1 val1 val2 val3 -key1 val11 val12 val13
 Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

 Eshell V6.3  (abort with ^G)
 1> init:get_argument(key1).
 {ok,[["val1","val2","val3"],["val11","val12","val13"]]}
 2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about processing command line arguments in the Erlang doc, [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).